# swift Cannot convert return expression of type to return type Presenter

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, combine

I have MVVM ios App. I am using SpaceXAPI to get the RoadSter data to represent it on View.I have this issue on RoadsterViewModel

> RoadsterViewModel.swift Cannot convert return expression of type '()'
> to return type 'RoadstarPresenter'

```
import Foundation
import Combine
final class RoadsterViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject {
    private var task: Cancellable? = nil
    private var roadster: RoadsterModel? = nil
    @Published var presenters: RoadstarPresenter? = nil
    
    
    
    func onAppear(){
        self.task = Service.standard.get(path: .roadster , responseType:RoadsterModel.self)
            .map{[weak self] in
                self?.roadster = $0
                guard let roadster = self?.roadster  else {
                    return
                }
                
                return RoadstarPresenter(with: roadster)
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion:{_ in },receiveValue:{  [weak self] presenters in
                self?.presenters = presenters
                
            })
    }
}


import Foundation
struct RoadstarPresenter{
    let image:String?
    let title:String?
    let detail:String?
    
    init(with model:RoadsterModel) {
        self.image = model.flickrImages.first ?? ""
        self.title = model.name
        self.detail = model.details
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `map`, you can't have a `return` with nothing following it. `return nil`?

Comment: Thank you. Can you convert your comment to Answer

Comment: Just a typo, really. If you want to post an answer, you're welcome to.

Answer (score 0):

this onApper function after return nil

```
 func onAppear(){
        self.task = Service.standard.get(path: .roadster , responseType:RoadsterModel.self)
            .map{[weak self] in
                self?.roadster = $0
                guard let roadster = self?.roadster  else {
                    return nil
                }
                
                return RoadstarPresenter(with: roadster)
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion:{_ in },receiveValue:{  [weak self] presenter in
                self?.presenter = presenter
                
            })
    }
```